# How to add language support for full text search?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, stop-words

I want implement support of full text search for some language (Ukrainian) in MongoDB. What resources I must provide (or make)? Do I need to make some changes in Mongo sources?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/ - Should be a good starting point.

Comment: You'd need to add some resources to the server - a stemming algorithm and stopword list, for starters. If you feel qualified to implement things like that, I'd post to the [mongodb-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-dev) user group asking how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Ukrainian stop-words are not currently supported. For Cyrillic, Russian so far

Here you have the listing of fully supported languages:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/